# Go back to previous activity manually

Tags: android

Here's my code:
Activity1 (main): Checks if the db has any rows. If not, load the main view. If it has at least 1 start Activity2

```
    int num = db.numOfRows();
    if(num==0){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
    }
```

Activity 2: Loads the moreprojects view which populates table rows with db information.

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.moreprojects);
        populateRows();
```

non-activity dbhandler: contains all the database stuff (db mentioned in Activity1). Now, on Activity2 you can delete the rows which calls the method below. Within that if(num==0) I would like to have Activity2 call Activity1. Activity1 is the screen which allows for creating of projects.

```
public void deleteContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_blah, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    int num = numOfRows();
    Log.d("Testing","Number of rows: "+num);

    if(num ==0){
        //go back to Activity1
    }
    db.close();
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

I've been trying multiple different things such as:
creating a method in activity2 which does finish();... but that doesn't do anything. It just seems to reload Activity2.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) should go back since you opened activity2 using startActivity and not startActivityForResult :

```
public void deleteContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_blah, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    int num = numOfRows();
    Log.d("Testing","Number of rows: "+num);

    if(num ==0){
        finish();
    }
    db.close();
}
```

this supposes that deleteContact is in Activity2

**EDIT :**

calling finish will only call Activity1's onResume method i guess
To go back to Activity1 and restart it you can :

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity1.class));
```

check android's [activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: Delete contact is in dbhandler (non activity). What I did was create a method in activity2 that executes the finish. Created the object in dbhandler that calls the method and executes the finish. The finish doesn't seem to restart the onCreate() in Activity1. Is that possible?

Comment: maybe just return num from deleteContact and in  activity2's when calling deleteContact test if num == 0 then call finish();

Comment: How would i go about restarting onCreate? Or I guess restarting the entire Activity1?

Comment: Or i would have to do ForResult and send the value back... then do an if within the main if which contains this: startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class)); and basically duplicate it. ... hm.

Answer (score 0):

When you wanna finish Activity A and back to Activity 2 just call finish(); in A , and that will work

Answer (score 0):

Just call **finish** on your activity.
Than is goes back to the caller

Answer (score 0):

```
finish();
```

should do the trick. If that is "reloading activity2" then I would add some log statements to both Activities that will print out your `num` variable. My guess is that somehow num is 0 in Activity2, but num is somehow being > 0 when Activity1 takes focus, which would then re-launch Activity2 because of your if statement.