# How to perform back button action in another app?

Tags: java, android, back-button, pid

i want simple app to kill the activity from the stack in current visible activities... How to implement the app to run in background and close activities in running apps?

Comment: What's your use case?  I can't think of a reason to do this which is not bad.  But in any case, thankfully, Android will not let you do this.

Comment: You can't. Android manages activities, if you have a better way submit a patch.

Comment: If one of the answers has pointed you in the right direction please mark it as the accepted answer now, thank you

Comment: its not the solution of my problem, cuz I want to remove in other apps like facebook the highest activity on the stack. I have the packageName, the topActiivty but cant remove the activity from stack to go one level down... I understand that can do only the system itself but i was hopeing to send an intent or so the signal to kill the highest activity on stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are your own activities, you need to declare an action on the activity you want to be closeable, then call that action from the other app. The closing activity will get notified in <kbd>onNewIntent()</kbd> where you can check the action and call finish

In closable activity:

```
   @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       if ("action.action.myactionstring".equals(intent.getAction())) {
           finish();
       }
   }
```

In closeable activity mainfest

```
   <activity android:name=".CloseableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="action.action.myactionstring" />
            ...
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

In the other activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("action string");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Remember that you would need to launch the target activity using [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) in order for `onNewIntent()` to be called.

Comment: thanks, but just one app is mine.. I want to perform the back Button action in other apps

Comment: You can't affect another app, if it was on the same backstack/task then maybe you could clear_top or similar (i'm not compeletly clear on all the flags), but it will be on it's own task and you can never directly invoke the back button and cause the other app to receive onBackPressed

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **finish();** Command? [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129965/go-back-to-previous-activity-manually)

Comment: finish... yes, but how to perform it knowing the package name or even the top activity from an app thats not mine.. I want just send a signal to other apps to close the highest activity from stack - not clear the whole stack, just take down one from the top.